# get text of vertex on click in MxGraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, mxgraph, draw.io

I am working on mxGraph, I need to get the the text of clicked vertex. The click should be right click.
By default, on right click on vertex,a menu is shown, I have added my custom menu on it, and on that Custom Menu click I need to get the Text of clicked vertex.

Please see the below image:

[image]

On the "Custom Menu", I have opened the form, Now i need to get the text of clicked vertex so that I can fill the input field in form.

this is my event on custom menu click:

```
this.addAction("custommenu",function() {
        showPieMenuForm();
});
```

I ned to send the clicked vertex text in the `showPieMenuForm(clickedVertexTExt)`

any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
this.addAction("custommenu",function({
        var cell = graph.getSelectionCell();
        if (cell != null) {
            showPieMenuForm(this);
        }
});
```